# How to fix this error with pygame and fonts

Tags: python, pygame, mouse, tracking

```
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

coordinate = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Mouse Tracker")

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)
text = font.render(coordinate, True, (255,255,255))

while True:

screen.fill((0,0,0))

screen.blit(text, (10, 10))


for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()

pygame.display.update()
clock.tick(60)
```

I am trying to make a program that tracks your mouse and shows the coordinates of it on the sreen. I get an error saying:
text = font.render(coordinate, True, (255,255,255))

```
TypeError: text must be a unicode or bytes.
```

I am using Python 3.9.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are couple of changes to be made:

1. `coordinate = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` returns a tuple which the variable `coordinate` is assigned to. The `font.render()` method takes a string as an argument not a tuple. So first you need to render the `str(coordinate)` and not just the `coordinate` which is actually a tuple. You can read more about rendering the font in pygame [here](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/font.html#pygame.font.Font.render)

```py
text = font.render(str(coordinate), True, (255,255,255)) #Rendering the str(coordinate)
```

2. Step one alone won't make your code functional, there are still  some problems in your code. For blitting the coordinate of the mouse to the screen, you need to get the mouse coordinates at every single frame. For that to function you need to place the line `coordinate = pygame.mouse.get_pos()` in the `while True` loop, along with this you also need to place this line `text = font.render(str(coordinate), True, (255,255,255))` in the while  loop

```py
import pygame,sys
#[...]#part of code
while True:
    coordinate = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #Getting the mouse coordinate at every single frame
    text = font.render(str(coordinate), True, (255,255,255))
    #[...] other part of code
```

So the final working code should look somewhat like:

```py
import pygame, sys

pygame.init()
clock = pygame.time.Clock()



screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1000,800), 0, 32)
pygame.display.set_caption("Mouse Tracker")

font = pygame.font.Font(None, 25)


while True:
    coordinate = pygame.mouse.get_pos() #Getting the mouse coordinate at every single frame
    text = font.render(str(coordinate), True, (255,255,255)) #Rendering the str(coordinate)
    screen.fill((0,0,0))

    screen.blit(text, (10, 10))


    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:#
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)
```

Comment: Glad I could help you :)